Data Retrieval Using Flow Not Working Properly From Composable
Function in my Dao file is:
@Query("SELECT * from appData WHERE type = :type ORDER BY id DESC")
    fun getData(type: String): Flow<List<AppData>>

The database contains a column of automatically generated int primary key 'id', a column of string named 'type', and another string column named 'content'.
A Part of code from my composable function is:
val currentRetrievedDate: Date = Date()
    val currentDate: String = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(currentRetrievedDate)

    var lastDateObjectList by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList<AppData>()) }

    LaunchedEffect(streakCounterViewModel) {
        coroutineScope {
            streakCounterViewModel.appDataRepository.getDataStream("lastDate")
                .collect { newDataList ->
                    lastDateObjectList = newDataList as List<AppData>
                }
        }
    }

    if (lastDateObjectList.size>1){/*TODO*/
        for (i in 1 until lastDateObjectList.size){
            LaunchedEffect (Unit){
                streakCounterViewModel.deleteData(id = lastDateObjectList[i]!!.id,
                    type = lastDateObjectList[i]!!.type,
                    content = lastDateObjectList[i]!!.content)
            }
        }
    }

    val lastDateObject: AppData?/* = lastDateObjectList[0] ?: null*/
    lastDateObject = if (lastDateObjectList.isNotEmpty())
        lastDateObjectList[0]
    else null

        var lastDate = lastDateObject?.content ?: "00-00-0000"

    var currentStreakObjectList by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList<AppData>()) }

    LaunchedEffect(streakCounterViewModel) {
        coroutineScope {
            streakCounterViewModel.appDataRepository.getDataStream("currentStreak")
                .collect { newDataList ->
                    currentStreakObjectList = newDataList as List<AppData>
                }
        }
    }

    if (currentStreakObjectList.size>1){
        for (i in 1 until currentStreakObjectList.size){
            LaunchedEffect (Unit){
            streakCounterViewModel.deleteData(id = currentStreakObjectList[i]!!.id,
                type = currentStreakObjectList[i]!!.type,
                content = currentStreakObjectList[i]!!.content)
            }
        }
    }

    val currentStreakObject: AppData?/* = currentStreakObjectList[0] ?: null*/
    currentStreakObject = if (currentStreakObjectList.isNotEmpty())
        currentStreakObjectList[0]
    else null

        var currentStreak = currentStreakObject?.content ?: "0"

In this code, the last login time and last streak of user is already saved, we just have to fetch the data from the local database, make sure that there are not more than 1 occurrences of same data type in the database, and then use that data. But this, instead of using the database values, uses 00-00-0000 as the lastDate, and uses "0" as the currentStreak (which should only be used for the first not, and in some rare situations only), and is not able to retrieve data from the database properly.
The data saving and updating logic is working fine, but only the retrieval part is causing some issue.
